# how to reload an image using kivy in order to visualize the modification made on it in real time?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

i'm trying to build an app using python, kivy and Pillow that allows the user to create cards. the user will be able to select a template from available templates using a Spinner, draw a title on it , paste an image on this template, and save the result as png. while doing the image manipulation, the user should be able to visualize the changes (like visualize the change of the template when passing from a template to another). here is a simple code that takes the example of changing the templates:

test.py:

```
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from PIL import Image as PILImage


class Test(MDScreen):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.template_path = 'assets/templates/white_template.png'
        
        self.generate_card()
        
    
    def update_template(self, template):
        if template == "White":
           self.template_path ='assets/templates/white_template.png'

        else:
           self.template_path = 'assets/templates/black_template.png'
           
        self.generate_card()
        
    def generate_card(self):
        open_template = PILImage.open(self.template_path)
        template_image = open_template.resize((421,614),PILImage.ANTIALIAS)
        card_save_path= "assets/preview/"
        card_name= "card.png"
        template_image.save(card_save_path+card_name)
```

test.kv:

```
<Test>:
    
    MDFloatLayout:
        
        size: root.width , root.height
        
        MDFloatLayout:
            size_hint: 1, .7
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .65}

            MDBoxLayout:
                size_hint: .6, .9
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                
                Image:
                    id: preview_image
                    source: "assets/preview/card.png"
    
        MDBoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, .3
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .15}
            md_bg_color:"yellow"
            padding: "10dp", "10dp", "10dp","5dp"
            
            Spinner:
                size_hint_x: .9
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
                text: "White"
                values: "White", "Black"
                on_text: root.update_template(self.text)
```

each time a template is selected, the self.generate_card() is called which leads to the save of the image (overwrite) with new modification in the path 'assets/preview/card.png'. is there any way to use the Image.reload() method to load the image from this path each time self.generate_card() is called and display it in the preview section using the image id (in kivy file).

Comment: Have you tried just calling the `reload()` method at the end of the `generate_card()` method?

Comment: @JohnAnderson, Thanks for your response . Based on the documentation , we should first create (or call) the image object, then reload it . (im = Image(source = '1.jpg')
# -- do something --
im.reload()). In my case I tried to call the image using the ids, pass it in __init__ then reload at the end of generate_card(). here is what i did:  class Test(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.preview_image = self.ids.preview_card

Comment: @JohnAnderson here is what i did: class Test(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.preview = self.ids.preview_image  
        ...rest of code...
    def generate_card(self):
        ...rest of code...
        self.preview.reload()

but i got this error: 
line 15, in __init__
    self.preview = self.ids.preview_image

  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Comment: Can't follow your logic. Try just adding `self.ids.preview_image.reload()` at the end of `generate_card()`.

Comment: Yes, I tried adding self.ids.preview_image.reload() at the end of generate_card(), but i'm getting this error after running the app:                                                                                   KeyError: 'preview_image'

line 41, in generate_card
  self.ids.preview_image.reload()  
      
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Comment: That's probably due to calling `self.generate_card()` in the `__init__()` method. I don't think you need that. It is being called before the `ids` are set. Try just removing that line.

Comment: @JohnAnderson thank you so much for trying to help me. I proposed the issue to Chatgpt and it fixed it. after trying many approaches, gpt proposed something called "on_kv_post" method. first i should have added preview_image = ObjectProperty(None) before __init__. Then i added preview_image = self.ids.preview_image, preview_image.source = path_to_save, preview_image.reload() inside generate_card(). then gpt proposed to add this function after __init__  :def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        super(Test, self).on_kv_post(base_widget)
        self.generate_card(). Now it works perfectly.

Comment: @JohnAnderson thank you sir for your feedback. You are absolutely right, i shouldn't call self.generate_card() in the __init__() method. removing it from __init__ and adding 'def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        super(Test, self).on_kv_post(base_widget)
        self.generate_card()' fixed the issue. Thank you again .